# WebKitView occupies the entire screen

Tags: swift, webkit

I have a simple WebKitView question.  I only set the WebKitView in the IB to show on the bottom 3/4 part of the screen, but it is occupying the entire page when loading the website.  Any ideas why this is the case?

Also I have another question, why is WebView deprecated and is WebKitView better than WebView?  Does it load faster, etc?

Thanks for any responses.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
   webView = WKWebView()

    //If you want to implement the delegate
    //webView?.navigationDelegate = self

   view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.ca") {
        let req = URLRequest(url: url)
       webView?.load(req)
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove loadView method,
following code is enough :)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.ca") {
            let req = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView?.load(req)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but this did not work for me.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: It works for me... Is your webView is connected with storyboard? See marked red section in attached image